# How to use telnetlib in python the same way as telnetlib3 (windows)?

Tags: python, telnet

I have a python code with `telnetlib3` as follows:

```
import asyncio
import telnetlib3

async def foo():
    reader, writer = await telnetlib3.open_connection("192.168.200.10", 9000)
    data = await asyncio.wait_for(reader.read(4096), timeout=2)
    print(data)

asyncio.run(foo())
```

that is able to connect to a telnet service and returns the following expected output on a Linux and Windows system:

```
Terminal emulator detected (unknown), switching to interactive shell

Debug server connected. Waiting for commands (or 'exit')...
Supported client terminals: telnet, screen, PuTTY.

prompt >>
```

However, when I use `telnetlib` as in the following example:

```
import time
import telnetlib

session = telnetlib.Telnet("192.168.200.10", 9000, 2)
received = b""
t0 = time.time()
while time.time() - t0 < 2:
    data = session.read_very_eager()
    if data:
        received += data
        t0 = time.time()
print(received)
```

the output is something like

```
b'\x1b[0G\x1b[0G'
```

on Linux and windows.

How can I modify the first code example (using **`telnetlib`**) so I receive the "interactive welcome message" as I do with `telnetlib3` on **Windows**?

- windows: windows10, python 3.10.11
- linux (VM on windows): Ubuntu 20.04.6, python 3.8.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that [`telnetlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/telnetlib.html) is deprecated since Python version 3.11, and *will be removed* in version 3.13.
Your Python version is OK, but... don't upgrade it too quickly!

`telnetlib` is a bit lower-level than [`telnetlib3`](https://pypi.org/project/telnetlib3/): it does not automatically handle some of the telnet protocol interactions that `telnetlib3` does for you. The binary output you are seeing is likely part of the Telnet protocol negotiation that `telnetlib3` is handling automatically, but `telnetlib` is not.

You can try and mirror the functionality of your `telnetlib3` version by manually handling the Telnet protocol negotiation, with [`telnetlib.Telnet.set_option_negotiation_callback`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/telnetlib.html#telnetlib.Telnet.set_option_negotiation_callback). It does *not* handle all cases - it is only designed to work with your specific server.
Inspired from "[`robot.libraries.Telnet`](https://robot-framework.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/robot/libraries/Telnet.html)", but... very much simplified.
See also "[Python `telnetlib.WILL` Examples](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/113281/telnetlib.WILL) "

```py
import time
import telnetlib

session = telnetlib.Telnet()

# That is a helper function to handle Telnet options
def handle_option(tsocket, command, option):
    if command == telnetlib.DO and option == telnetlib.TTYPE:
        tsocket.sendall(telnetlib.IAC + telnetlib.WILL + telnetlib.TTYPE)
        tsocket.sendall(telnetlib.IAC + telnetlib.SB + telnetlib.TTYPE + b'\0' + b'unknown' + telnetlib.IAC + telnetlib.SE)
    elif command in (telnetlib.DO, telnetlib.DONT):
        tsocket.sendall(telnetlib.IAC + telnetlib.WONT + option)
    elif command in (telnetlib.WILL, telnetlib.WONT):
        tsocket.sendall(telnetlib.IAC + telnetlib.DONT + option)

session.set_option_negotiation_callback(handle_option)

session.open("192.168.200.10", 9000)
received = b""
t0 = time.time()
while time.time() - t0 < 2:
    data = session.read_very_eager()
    if data:
        received += data
        t0 = time.time()

print(received.decode())
```

The `handle_option` function is a callback that `telnetlib` will use to respond to Telnet option commands from the server. It essentially it is telling the server that we will handle terminal type (`TTYPE`) options and that we will not handle any other options.

That code should give you similar results to your `telnetlib3` version, but it is a bit more complex because `telnetlib` requires you to handle more of the protocol details manually.

Also, I have used `decode()` method (as [in this example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/telnetlib.html#telnet-example)) at the end to convert binary data into string. Do remove it if your data is not text.

Answer (score 0):

```
import time
import telnetlib

def negotiate_telnet_options(telnet_session):
    # Send the Telnet option negotiation
    telnet_session.sock.sendall(telnetlib.IAC + telnetlib.WILL + telnetlib.TERMINAL_TYPE)
    telnet_session.sock.sendall(telnetlib.IAC + telnetlib.DO + telnetlib.TERMINAL_TYPE)

    # Process Telnet option negotiation response
    telnet_session.read_until(telnetlib.IAC + telnetlib.DO + telnetlib.TERMINAL_TYPE, timeout=2)
    telnet_session.read_until(telnetlib.IAC + telnetlib.WILL + telnetlib.TERMINAL_TYPE, timeout=2)

def read_until_prompt(telnet_session):
    received = b""
    t0 = time.time()
    while time.time() - t0 < 2:
        data = telnet_session.read_very_eager()
        if data:
            received += data
            if b'prompt >>' in received:
                return received
            t0 = time.time()
    return received

def main():
    session = telnetlib.Telnet("192.168.200.10", 9000, 2)

    # Perform Telnet option negotiation
    negotiate_telnet_options(session)

    # Wait for the welcome message or prompt
    received = read_until_prompt(session)
    print(received)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but your suggestion does not solve my problem. I double checked that all values, IP addresses, ports, strings are correct, edited them, changed them, inserted prints etc., but I get a complete empty byte string at the end of the code. Something is still off. Maybe my windows is misconfigured or has a very specific telnet related bug...